Free folder music player for Windows
For Windows I am looking for a free music player with the following requirements:

Must be free
Has the ability to create playlists. One playlist is usually the files in a folder.
Has the ability to "rate" the songs.
Shows the playlist with the following attributes: filename, rating, length (time), optionally filesize. Other attributes like title, artist, album, track number, etc. are not of importance.
Has the ability to play the playlist in some order, or randomized.

My music is locally stored and organized in folders. One folder corresponds usually to one "playlist".
I have tried:

WINAMP seems to come close, but it does not show the rating of the songs of a playlist. Without that information I do not know what songs have been rated and what songs I still have to rate...
VLC, but it does not display the file name (only URI), it's not possible to hide the title and songs can't be rated.
foobar2000, but it can't show nor edit the rating.


You also asked this question about a year ago, but yeah, I see some programs fail to comply with the requirements.

MusicBee

Must be free

It's free for personal use. Free as in beer, i.e. gratis, not open-source. I couldn't find a license online, but there's a License.rtf included in the portable version.

Has the ability to create playlists. One playlist is usually the files in a folder.

Drag'n'drop a folder into the playlist explorer.

Has the ability to "rate" the songs.

Once you configured the columns to include the rating, you can set the rating easily with a single click, or you can use the context menu.

Shows the playlist with the following attributes: filename, rating, length (time), optionally filesize.

Needs your configuration, but then has it. See the screenshot below.

Has the ability to play the playlist in some order, or randomized.

You can turn on shuffle and/or repeat mode.
Here's the main playlist layout, configured with the columns as you like it. It will remember the settings.

Here's the context menu for rating. Except for removing a rating, you'll rarely use that, since it's much simpler by clicking the rating column.

Pros:

it can scan a music folder with 34700 songs without crashing. That may take a while, though.

Cons:

it may take a while to configure the UI at first run. In the screenshot above, I have removed a lot of fluff. Hint: use this little icon:




And thanks for the question. It might happen that I have a new favorite music player now :-)

I also recommend MusicBee. As the other answer says, it supports all your needs. I find it particularly useful because it can automatically copy playlists to your phone - keeping relative filepaths - so your folder structure on your phone is exactly the same as on your computer (assuming your playlists and tracks are sensibly contained in the same parent folder).
